# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 for FBSDKLoginCore

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook-sdk-4.0, fbsdk

I recently encountered this error when trying to implement Facebook Login using Parse SDK and Facebook SDK.

I took the following steps:

[image]

Imported the following frameworks

[image]

Listed them under bridging header

[image]

I get the following errors after I built my project.

Solutions that I attempted:

-Removing the -ObjC from "Other Linkers" and adding $(inherited)
-Changing Architecture to "STANDARD" 
-Selecting libz.1.2.5.dylib build and run

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

UPDATE:

Here's my command line as requested.

[image]

Comment: On Which Version of Xcode you are running becuase In the Xcode 7, There are no more dynamic binary libraries (.dylib) instead of it offer .tbd libraries and I thing that may be recognised by OS X EI Capitan & OS X EI Capitan has support for the .tbd (file extension), which is not available with OS X Yosemite?

So the project that has (.dylib) can run only in the lower version of Xcode 7.

Comment: @Abhishek Correct. I am using Xcode 7 and OS X El Capitan.

Comment: Add .tbd libraries in place of your dylib..

Comment: @Abhishek I tried replacing all 4 of them with tbd libraries. and I am getting the same error. :/

Comment: May be you are using the older version of frameworks also from your compilation errors its look like you are missing to import some frameworks in your project because reference from error is generally when we missing to import required frameworks.

Comment: Are you using the most latest version of Facebook SDK? Cause may be framework internally uses the dylib.

Comment: @Abhishek Correct, I'm using the latest version of FacebookSDK. I'll try to switch back to dylib files.

Answer (score 1):

Its about your link order. LoginKit needs symbols from CoreKit but cant find them due to your wrong link order. Thats why you get the `Undefined symbols` error message.

Solution:
**Reverse your link order.**

Go to *your target in Xcode -> Build phases -> Link binary with libraries* 
and then drag those two libraries around. :)

Comment: I tried that , I'm still getting those four errors even after I have dragged CoreKit before LoginKit.

Comment: Hi. Can you additionally please provide the compiling command line. It is visible in the error summary in Xcode. I want to see the linker flags and parameters there and compare them to the output of my setup. thank you.

Comment: Yes , certainly! I will update my error summary. Thank you Markus!